# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_updatedFibers')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, package.json

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_updatedFibers')

[image]

#### index.ts

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "reflect-metadata";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

root.render(<App />);

reportWebVitals();
```

#### app.tsx

```
const App: React.FC<Props> = () => {


  const notistackRef = useRef<ProviderContext>();
  const onClickDismiss = (key: string | number) => () => {
    notistackRef &&
      notistackRef.current &&
      notistackRef.current.closeSnackbar(key);
  };

  return (
    <IoCProvider>
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={ptBRLocale}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
          <AuthProvider>
            <SnackbarProvider
              autoHideDuration={5000}
              maxSnack={3}
              preventDuplicate
              //@ts-ignore
              ref={notistackRef}
              action={(key) => (
                <IconButton size="small" onClick={onClickDismiss(key)}>
                  <CloseIcon htmlColor="#fff" />
                </IconButton>
              )}
            >
              <CssBaseline />

              <HomeUserContextProvider>
                <Routes />
              </HomeUserContextProvider>
            </SnackbarProvider>
          </AuthProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    </IoCProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "portal-cliente-atem",
  "version": "0.1.101",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@datadog/browser-rum": "^4.23.3",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "1.x",
    "@fontsource/montserrat": "^4.5.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7.1.20",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.8",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.2",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.5",
    "framer-motion": "^8.4.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.14.1",
    "inversify": "^5.0.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^11.0.2",
    "lodash.groupby": "^4.6.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "notistack": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-json-view": "^1.19.1",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.1.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^3.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.29.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "start:prod": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='production' react-app-rewired start",
    "start:homologation": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='homologation' react-app-rewired start",
    "build:homologation": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT='homologation' react-app-rewired build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.groupby": "^4.6.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/pdfmake": "^0.1.16",
    "@types/react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-text-mask": "^5.4.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.7",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "2.1.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2016",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types",
      "node_modules/reflect-metadata/types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
}
```

Comment: That would suggest that `ReactCurrentBatchConfig$3.transition`  is `undefined` ... which isn't `null`, therefore that code in the picture will naturally break

Comment: @JaromandaX -> https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/issues/2134

Comment: a closed issue? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯